# JavaFX - при вызове функций, которые долго выполняются, происходит ошибка "Платформа Java не работает "

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Здравствуйте, пишу приложение на *java*. В качестве *GUI* использую *JavaFX* (скажу сразу, что при использование swt данной проблемы нет).
Итак, есть некоторая функция, *длительность выполнения* которой не менее 30 сек на моем ноутбуке. В ней происходит довольно сложная обработка данных.
При её вызове буквально через 1-2 секунды появляется окошко, что "Платформа Java(TM) Platform SE binary не работает" с текстом "Возникшая проблема привела к прекращению работы программы...".
Как решить данную проблему я не знаю.
Может быть подскажет кто, как вызывать методы, которые выполняются довольно долго и при этом приложение на JavaFX не вырубало вот так..?
Вызываю метод при выборе элемента всплывающего меню:

```
itemGoIT.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {     

   @Override      

   public void handle(ActionEvent event) {      

      context.hide(); //убираем меню

      System.out.println("старт " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

      JniTest SS = new JniTest();

      try {
          //вызываем метод
          SS.showString();
       }
       catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
          System.out.println("метод не найден (" + e + ")");
       }

       System.out.println("завершено " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }    
});
```

Comment: покажите код, где вызывается данная функция

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, дополнила вопрос этим куском кода

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы *подвешиваете* поток обрабатывающий события **ui**.
Чтобы этого не происходило, нужно вынести все тяжелые операции в отдельный поток, т.е. ваш код должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("старт " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        JniTest SS = new JniTest();

        try {
            //вызываем метод
            SS.showString();
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("метод не найден (" + e + ")");
        }

        System.out.println("завершено " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }).start();
```

Comment: то есть, будет что-то вроде: itemGoIT.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
Override      
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {      
    context.hide(); //убираем меню

   new Thread(() -> {
        ...
    }).start();                                                                                              });

Comment: или вызов тяжеловесных функций вовсе не стоит вызывать при обработке событий ui?

Comment: если я при обработке события запускаю новый поток, в котором вызываю эту функцию, происходит то же самое - завершается работа приложения

Comment: @Наталья значит, проблема в логике, что там происходит в той операции?

Comment: сама эта функция работает корректно. Я вызывала её в простой программе, где нет GUI

Comment: ок, а вот это что такое     context.hide(); //убираем меню ?

Comment: если оставить следующий код для обработки события: itemGoIT.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {                    Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {                                   new Thread(() -> { ... }).start(); });                                                             всё равно программа виснет и прекращает исполнение

Comment: выходит проблема в том, что вы запускаете в методе showString